# python use turtle draw a track n field race track

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Write a program using the turtle that draws a track with several lanes. You may ask the user to enter an integer in between 1 and 8 for the number of lanes. A track typically consists of 2 Straightaways with semicircles on both sides. A lane is enclosed between two of these shapes. Thus, a track with 6 lanes should have 7 figures of similar shape, enclosed in one another.

The question as stated above is the outcome i am trying to produce. Each line of track keeps starting in the same line. Please help! Should i be trying to alter the starting position?

```
import turtle

def main():
    side = 80
    n = int(input("How many lanes do would you want?\n"))


    turtle.pendown()
    for cnt in range(n+1):
        race = turtle.Turtle()
        race.forward(side)
        race.circle(side/2,180)
        race.forward(side)
        race.circle(side/2,180)
        side = side = side + 20

main()
```

Comment: `side = side = side + 20` looks wrong

Comment: Yea type-o didn't even c that thanks but still draws wrong!

Comment: I don't fully envision the task as hand (can't see how the tracks should be shown) and I don't know `turtle` but it seems you would have to use the `cnt` to offset the start position of each lane by the width of something (this is where I don't understand the task as hand)

Comment: @RobertEkendahl http://www.sportspectator.com/fancentral/track/guide04.html is what im trying to draw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some important things to note:

1. `turtle.pendown()` does not change the particular instance or `race`, you want `race.pendown()`
2. Each time you do `race = turtle.Turtle()`, you make a new instance of `race` Take this statement out side of the for loop.
3. Each loop you make you need to move `race` (for spacing of the tracks), which you can do with:

   ```
   race.penup() #Inside for loop.
   race.right(90)
   race.forward(20) #I think it should be 20...
   race.right(-90)
   ```

Just to be clear this is what it looks like in the end:

import turtle

```
def main():
    side = 80
    n = int(input("How many lanes do would you want?\n"))

    race = turtle.Turtle()
    for cnt in range(n+1):
        race.forward(side)
        race.circle(side,180)
        race.forward(side)
        race.circle(side,180)
        side = side = side + 20
        race.penup() #Inside for loop.
        race.right(90)
        race.forward(20) #I think it should be 20...
        race.right(-90)
        race.backward(10)
        race.pendown()

main()
```

Meanwhile, in the midst of 3 lanes:

[image: Turtle]

Even more refactored code:

```
import turtle

def create_track(n, side=80, change=20):
    race = turtle.Turtle()
    for cnt in range(n+1):
        race.forward(side)
        race.circle(side,180)
        race.forward(side)
        race.circle(side,180)
        side = side + change
        race.penup()
        race.right(90)
        race.forward(change)
        race.right(-90)
        race.backward(change/2)
        race.pendown()

def main():
    n = int(input("How many lanes do would you want?\n"))
    create_track(n)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: thanks for point 1 & 2. When i use point 3 it changes the intersecting line from the bottom 1 to the top 1. Trying to play around with the angles but to no avail.

Comment: @user3723557: Are you saying you want to invert the drawing directions? Draw inwards instead of outwards?

Comment: No, even with the race.penup code, a line still intersects. It does not matter if it draws inwards or outwards.

Comment: Further update: Added `backwards(10)`, prevents lopsidedness.

Comment: I CAN'T THANK YOU ENOUGH! THAT WORKS!